# Stay on the same page if login process failed

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I have 3 php pages which are index.php, login.php and loginSuccess.php index.php contains only the login form and login.php contains php codes for login process.

```
<?php

session_start();

include './dbConnection.php';

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userNameText']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordText']);

$userName = stripslashes($name);
$userPassword = stripslashes($password);


$loginQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_Name ='$userName' AND Password ='$userPassword'";
$query = mysql_query($loginQuery);
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($result == 1){
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
    header("Location: loginSuccess.php");
}else{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

?>

What i want to do is staying in the index.php with an error message if the user types wrong login information. I have a jquery function below and i want to call it in the login.php's else condition.How can i do this ? Thanks for help.

```
$(function(){    
   $('#errorDiv').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page, you have to use AJAX instead of normal form submission.

Comment: @Barmar Actually i don't have an enough AJAX knowledge to makes it work.

Comment: Seems like a good reason to learn about AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do this would be something like this:

Change

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

to

```
// This is a bit rough, but, I'm guessing you're learning PHP
// so for now it'd do
header('Location: index.php?login=false');
```

And then in your index.php add something like

```
if ('false' === $_GET['login']) {
    echo 'Login failed!';
}
```

And you'll get a beautiful message saying "Login failed!" when... a login fails.

This is in no way the 'proper' way to do this, but, it will help you learn the logic you need to know for things like this to work.

Comment: Is this the only way to makes it except Ajax ?

Comment: This is just one way of making things happen from one page to another, it's not the only way, for example you could use the session to store whether the login succeeded, but I'd argue that it doesn't need to be kept in the session. If you were to do this with AJAX, you'd probably want to be outputting a JSON response and then picking that up with jQuery.

Comment: Hope you are not using this code anymore, it won't work well if you are not login.

Comment: This was posted quite a long time ago now. I think the OP was a beginner with PHP, so, they're probably not doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a loose example but hopefully you'll see the logic in it.

You could have a login form that POSTs to itself. Kind of like this:

```
<form method="POST action="?login">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

Then at the very top of the `index.php` page you could include the `login.php` file.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['login']){
        include 'login.php';
    }
?>
```

Do the same for wherever you want the JavaScript to go.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['login']){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript>
        $(function(){    
            $('#errorDiv').fadeIn();
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

If the user logged in successfully then you just redirect to the `loginSuccess.php`. If not everything loads again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't place your jQuery code inside `login.php`'s else condition because it will still perform the redirect. My suggestion is that you store the error message in a session variable and then continue with the redirect back to `index.php` where you check if that session variable is set. If it is, you can show the error message and then "unset" that session variable.

**index.php**

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['error'])): ?>
  <p class="error-message"><?php echo $_SESSION['error']; ?></p>
  <?php unset($_SESSION['error']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<form>...</form>
```

**login.php**

```
...
else {
  $_SESSION['error'] = 'the error message';
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```